# Wordpress not showing up when using PHP via plugin?

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I have installed a plugin ([use PHP in posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/)) for Wordpress, and am having some issues.

Here is my code (though I don't think its the issue)

```
$usertoget = $_GET['player'];
$partone = "http://website.co.uk/path/to/php/file.php";
if(strlen($usertoget) != 0) {
    $parttwo = "&player=";
    $partthree = $usertoget;
    $finalurl = $partone . $parttwo . $partthree;
    print '<iframe src="$finalurl"></iframe>';
}
else {
    print "<iframe src='/path/file.php'>";
}
```

The `iframe` gets printed perfectly and does what the target file should, but as you can see from this picture, messes up the formatting:

[image: Screenshot of the page]

1. No sidebar;
2. No footer;
3. No floating header.

I have noticed that the page source finishes the `iframe` and does nothing else except close (`</body></html>`). There is a lot of stuff after it that should appear but doesn't.

Another issue is, using `GET` requests (`/page/hello?player=9` and `/page/hello/?player=9`) returns a 404. Any ways to resolve this issue?

Does anybody know how I can fix this? I can post any more code if required :)

Any help would be appreciated :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If PHP suddenly stops sending the expected output, it usually means there's a PHP error.  Is there anything in your logs?  Have you tried [turning WP_DEBUG on](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

I'm surprised you say the iframe gets printed perfectly.  This line

```
print '<iframe src="$finalurl"></iframe>';
```

looks wrong to me (though it won't cause PHP to error).  If you have single quotes around a string, variables won't be evaluated.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986588/simple-php-dollar-evaluation-in-string-questions) for a little more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You have mistake in concatenation of $finalurl .you can check you html its print the $finalurl variable as it is.Its didn't outputted its values .I had check it.So you just have to concatenate the $finalurl variable correctly .Here is your code which i had made corrected.

```
$usertoget = $_GET['player'];
$partone = "http://website.co.uk/path/to/php/file.php";
if(strlen($usertoget) != 0) {
    $parttwo = "&player=";
    $partthree = $usertoget;
    $finalurl = $partone . $parttwo . $partthree;
    print '<iframe src='.$finalurl.'></iframe>';
}
else {
    print "<iframe src='/path/file.php'>";
}
```

if you have any query please comment bellow.