# Inserting cart and user data into mysql for a order system

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**Hi there,** 
I had a question up similar to this one, but seems like I'm stuck again.
I thought i got it to work until i tried to **add** more than one **product** to the **cart** and sending it to the **database**.

The *user data* (name, address, etc..) and the *cart data* for 1 **item** (product name, price, etc..) gets inserted without any problem. 
However, if i have lets say, 2 **items** in the cart when i try to send the data to the **database**, i get 2 rows as well so there it isn't any problem, but **both rows** are the **same item**, so it seem to count the same **id** twice, but there actually are 2 different **id's** in the **session**.

Any clues where I've gone wrong?

***I'm sending the data through a form!***

**Here's the code block:**

```
$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form1")) {

$insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO ordermodul (orgnummer, namn, levadress, faktadress, telefon, email, datum, summa, nmr) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, now(), %s, %s)",
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['orgnum'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['namn'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['levadress'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['faktadress'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['telefon'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['email'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['summa'], "text"),
                   GetSQLValueString($_POST['nmr'], "text"));

mysql_select_db($database_vesundberg_eu, $vesundberg_eu);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $vesundberg_eu) or die(mysql_error());

$order_id = mysql_insert_id();

if ($order_id) {

$quantity = $each_item['quantity'];
implode ( ',', array_values($each_item));
$line_cost = $price;

foreach ($_SESSION['cart_array'] as $each_item) {
    $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT id, productname, price FROM products WHERE id = %d;", '$item_id'); 
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                list($id, $price) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
                $line_cost = number_format($price * $quantity, 2);                  
            }   
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO cartorders (id, nmr, name, price, quantity) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
    GetSQLValueString("$artnummer", "int"),
    GetSQLValueString("$nmr", "int"),
    GetSQLValueString("$product_name", "text"),
    GetSQLValueString("$line_cost", "int"),
    GetSQLValueString("$quantity", "int"));

mysql_select_db($database_vesundberg_eu, $vesundberg_eu);
$Result1 = mysql_query($query, $vesundberg_eu) or die(mysql_error());
}}

$insertGoTo = "orders.php";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

**Here's the form:**

```
<form action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" method="post" name="form1" id="form1">
                   <table width="60%" border="0" align="center">
                      <tr align="center">
                        <td align="right">Org. nummer:</td>
                        <td align="left"><input name="orgnum" id="orgnum" type="text" /> *</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr align="center">
                        <td align="right">Företagsnamn:</td>
                        <td align="left"><input name="namn" type="text" id="namn" /> *</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr align="center">
                        <td align="right">Lev. adress:</td>
                        <td align="left"><input name="levadress" type="text" id="levadress" /> *</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr align="center">
                        <td align="right">Fakt. adress:</td>
                        <td align="left"><input name="faktadress" type="text" id="faktadress" /> *</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr align="center">
                        <td align="right">Telefon:</td>
                        <td align="left"><input name="telefon" type="text" id="telefon" /> *</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr align="center">
                        <td align="right">E-mail:</td>
                        <td align="left"><input name="email" type="text" id="email" /> *</td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr align="center">
                        <td align="right"></td>
                        <td align="left"><input name="summa" type="hidden" id="summa" value="<?php echo $cartTOTAL; ?>" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr align="center">
                        <td align="right"></td>
                        <td align="left"><input name="prodnum" type="hidden" id="prodnum" value="<?php echo $artnummer; ?>" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr align="center">
                        <td align="right"></td>
                        <td align="left"><input name="prodname" type="hidden" id="prodname" value="<?php echo $product_name; ?>" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr align="center">
                        <td align="right"></td>
                        <td align="left"><input name="price" type="hidden" id="price" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" /></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr align="center">
                        <td align="right"></td>
                        <td align="left"><input name="quantity" type="hidden" id="quantity" value="<?php echo $each_item['quantity']; ?>" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr align="center">
                        <td align="right"></td>
                        <td align="left"><input name="nmr" type="hidden" id="nmr" value="<?php echo $nmr; ?>" /></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr align="center">
                        <td align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td align="left"><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Skicka Order" /></td>
                      </tr> 
                    </table>
                    <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1" />
</form>
```

Comment: I hope it wasn't you that created the cringe-worthy `GetSQLValueString` function that allegedly does [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because that sort of thing is a super bad idea.

Comment: You should pick a correct answer in the questions you asked previously, and lacking answers may even provide an answer yourself.

Comment: Formatting line_cost and putting it into the cart will cause you pain when adding up the total, better format on output and store the cents value.

Comment: Can you show a vardump of $_SESSION['cart_array']?

Comment: @tadman No it wasn't me, i found it in another question, he got it to work, so figured i would try parts of his code, and i got it this far.

Comment: @Adder The answers from my previous questions seem to have disappeared, i had some good ideas in there, but today when i got to work they were gone, so for some reason i can't check them anymore. The line_cost will be removed, i got a proper setup from the cart array including cents value.

Comment: @miah Yes sure, here is the dump of $_SESSION['cart_array'] ... array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { ["item_id"]=> string(10) "2147483647" ["quantity"]=> int(1) } [1]=> array(2) { ["item_id"]=> string(8) "40734014" ["quantity"]=> int(1) } }

Comment: @JimSundqvist Don't use functions like that. Ever. They're nothing but trouble because they hide any flaws in the implementation, often leading to a false sense of security. You're basically re-inventing the [SQL placeholder system](http://bobby-tables.com/php) which does this in a reliable, standardized way.

Comment: and have you echoed out $sql for the inserts to see what it is trying to insert?  Also, per @tadman, you really should switch to one of the php classes (I like PDO, personally).

Comment: @miah i tried echoing out the $sql and it gives me "Resource id #8" I've tried adding items in different orders, but i still get the same echo. What does this mean? Also, i was thinking.. Do you think it would be better to only collect the user data in the form and somehow combine as i do now to input the data into the database, just that i get the data in some other way? I was thinking if the form only can pick up 1 item to send into the database, but in the query it sense two different ID's, then it inputs the same rows twice, or what do you think?

Comment: @tadman Normally i don't, but for this matter I'm willing to try any way possible, and then change it afterwards when i got a working code. I just cant seem to get the data to input right, it was the same with my original query, i didn't get all the items into the database either, i just got one item, or two of the same, like now.

Comment: I'm with @miah here. PDO works. What you have might work if you can figure out how to fix it, and even then you'll have something of dubious utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the id you are pulling from products is the same in each pass because

```
sprintf("SELECT id, productname, price FROM products WHERE id = %d;", '$item_id');
```

should evaluate to `"SELECT id, productname, price FROM products WHERE id = 0 "`  Because '$item_id' evaluates to the string "$item_id" which is not a number, rather than a string of the number. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2986642/1572077) has a nice break down of variable evalutation in strings

Change it to :

```
$sql = sprintf("SELECT id, productname, price FROM products WHERE id = %d;", $item_id);
```

Another issue is

```
list($id, $price) = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

The returned row from `$results` is made up of `("id","product_name", "price")`, so I'm guessing that `$price` actually has the `product name` in it, and `price` is going no where.

Comment: Thanks! this works, i changed the sprintf(), and added product name to the list(), also changed the $id variable to the correct one, and i got it to work. There is however one more issue with this, which I'm hoping you may try to help me with. I've got another column in the database called "nmr" (short for number). I was thinking to store a number in there for each session, i got the same "nmr" column in the user data. In the admin area i'm going to show the items to the correct user by this "nmr" column, the number has to be the same for each items corresponding to the user.

Comment: @JimSundqvist so what is your question?

Comment: Ok, I don't think that is what you want to do.  cartorders should have the foreign key(ordermodul_id), and ordermodul should have the foreign key(user_id).  You do not want to be keeping track of what the next number in nmr field is, as well as having to place it into three different tables.

Comment: I'm actually going with two tables for the order system, in one i store the user data and the other one i store the cart, but at the moment there is no way to keep track on what items will show at what order, that's where the "nmr" columns come in. I'm thinking something like a category system. Lets say the first order that comes into the store has a "nmr" (parent) of 7, then all the items the user has in his/her cart need to have the same "nmr"(Child) so it's easy to list it out in the admin area. You get what i mean?

Comment: currently i just have <?php $nmr = 1; ?> for testing purposes, but that means that all the orders have a nmr of 1, and so will all the items, so then every order will list all the items that are put into the order system, which will cause chaos. So i need to build a number system for each session and assign it to the variable $nmr  or something, but i can't seem to find a good way to do it.

Comment: if you are bound and determined to go this route, make nmr an auto-incrementing field inside of ordermodul.  This will let mysql take care of the counting, so all you do is insert a new ordermodul, grab the its nmr, and then use that nmr when you insert into the cart table.  The biggiest issue with this approach is that user data is repeated, so you may have to do some guess work when trying to view all of one client's orders.

Comment: I got an id column in the ordermodul table that is on auto increment, so putting nmr on auto increment is not possible as far as i know, and even so, is it even possible to get the value of the auto incremented id and put it into nmr in the cartorders table when they are being created at the same time? That's why i thought it would be easiest to find a way to generate the id before the insert. Is there any other way to do it than this?

Comment: Yes! Remove nmr from the ordermodul table, and use its auto-incremented id.  After you do your insert into ordermodul, run a select to pull out its ID.  I would recommend changing the nmr field in the carts table to be order_id, for clarity.

Comment: haha, i am most certainly blind, I'm already picking up the insert id! $order_id = mysql_insert_id(); changed the $nmr variable to $order_id in the second insert and it insert the correct id! Thanks a lot for the help you've given me! I truly appreciate it.